# Alternating output to create new matrix based on sum (matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I am looking to separate one input matrix (X) into two separate matrices, in an iterative process.

Is there any way to somewhat automate this process:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 6 7 9 8 7 9; 2 4 1 1 4 2];

n = length(Matrix(1,:))-1;

Matrix1 = X(:,1);

Matrix2 = X(:,2);

if sum(Matrix1(2,:)) < sum(Matrix2(2,:)),

    Matrix1 = [Matrix1 X(:,3)];

else

    Matrix2 = [Matrix2 X(:,3)]; 

end



Output:

X =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
     6     7     9     8     7     9
     2     4     1     1     4     2


Matrix1 =

     1     3
     6     9
     2     1


Matrix2 =

     2
     7
     4
```

The criteria is to work through the entire matrix X and then place into Matrix 1 or Matrix 2 based on the sum of the second row. So in this example the next column (#4) would be placed into Matrix 2 as sum of second row in Matrix1 is 15 > Matrix2 = 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This piece of code is already in a FOR loop ... will having a FOR loop within another, cause any issue?

Comment: No that is not a problem, it is done all the time. Just iterate in the FOR loop over the matrix columns and append each time to the matrix you want.